# How to get a transition for windows element like in scroll views?

Tags: windows, view, titanium, appcelerator, uiviewanimationtransition

I am trying to make a Demo in Appcelerator here is the code for it.

```
var tabGroup = Titanium.UI.createTabGroup();

var main_win = Titanium.UI.createWindow({  
     title:'Tab 1',
     backgroundColor:'#fff'
});

var win1 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({  
     title:'Tab 1',
     backgroundColor:'#fff'
});
var tab1 = Titanium.UI.createTab({ 
     title:'Tab 1',
     window:win1
});
var label1 = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
     text:'I am Window 1',
     win:win1
});
win1.add(label1);

var win2 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({  
     title:'Tab 2',
     backgroundColor:'#fff'
});
var tab2 = Titanium.UI.createTab({  
     title:'Tab 2',
     window:win2
});

var label2 = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
     text:'I am Window 2',
});
win2.add(label2);


tabGroup.addTab(tab1);  
tabGroup.addTab(tab2);  



main_win.open();

var button1 = Titanium.UI.createButton({
     title:"hello"
});
main_win.add(button1);
var button2 = Titanium.UI.createButton({
     title:"hello"
});
win1.add(button2);

button1.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
     tabGroup.open();
});

button2.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
     main_win.show();
     tabGroup.close();
});
```

Now button2 is not working in the desired way. I want to switch back to window_1 i.e the main window. What is going wrong with the code.

**EDIT**

I want to have a window (Can be a view/window or something else.) namely **main_win** which has a button named **button1**. When I click on **button1** it moves to another view which shows me two tabbed views namely **win1** and **win2** associated with **tab1** and **tab2**. Clicking on **tab1** will show **win1** and clicking on **tab2** will show **win2**. Both **win1** and **win2** have a button say **button2** clicking on which would send us back to the **main_win**. Also I want the transition to be like we are getting from scrollview by default.

Comment: @muhammadzeeshan if it had been working the desired way i havn't posted it here and asked for the solution.

Comment: @muhammadzeeshan if i would have known the desired way rather than asking i would have been answering here

Comment: @muhammadzeeshan check now i have editted the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always just think about tabGroups as windows.  It isn't documented, but you can use the `exitOnClose` property on tabGroups in Android.  Please see if the following code does what you need.  Titanium SDK 1.7.5 targeting Android 2.2

```
var main_win = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
    title : 'main_win',
    backgroundColor : '#fff'
});
var button1 = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    title : "open tabGroup",
    height:35,
    width:120
});
button1.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    tabGroup.open();
});
main_win.add(button1);

var win1 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
    title : 'Tab 1',
    backgroundColor : '#fff'
});
var tab1 = Titanium.UI.createTab({
    title : 'Tab 1',
    window : win1
});
var label1 = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
    text : 'I am Window 1',
    win : win1
});
win1.add(label1);
var button2 = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    title : "< back",
    top:5,
    left:5,
    height: 35,
    width: 80
});
win1.add(button2);
button2.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    tabGroup.close();
});

var win2 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
    title : 'Tab 2',
    backgroundColor : '#fff'
});
var tab2 = Titanium.UI.createTab({
    title : 'Tab 2',
    window : win2
});
var label2 = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
    text : 'I am Window 2',
});
win2.add(label2);
var button3 = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    title : "< back",
    top:5,
    left:5,
    height: 35,
    width: 80
});
win2.add(button3);
button3.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    tabGroup.close();
});

var tabGroup = Titanium.UI.createTabGroup({
    exitOnClose: false
});
tabGroup.addTab(tab1);
tabGroup.addTab(tab2);

main_win.open();
```

Comment: that was really great from ur side. I have read at several places that we can use tableview for our App and show views in them. Can i know how is that possible.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand the question you are asking in your comment.  Please create a new question if you need the answer to a different question.  If you need more to help with this question, please comment below.

Comment: I had read at several places that we can use table views for transition between two screen. To show/ hide or make a sliding view how is that possible ?

Comment: Hey @jeff  https://github.com/kwhinnery/NavigationController.git this is what I found after searching a lot for Views Navigation. I tried to implement it into my code but  this works  only with the IOS (ipad, iphone). Is there no way to achieve this in Android ?

Answer (score 0):

the tabgroup is a global element. i'm not sure if it is possible to close it - apparently not. you can jump to a tab with

```
tabGroup.setActiveTab(id_of_your_tab);
```

you need to build your own bar if you have to hide it.

> Also, is it possible to make a tabbed-view for views or scroll-views.

you can use a [scrollview](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.UI.ScrollView-object) on your window:

```
var scrollView = Titanium.UI.createScrollView({
    contentWidth:'auto',
    contentHeight:'auto',
    top:0,
    showVerticalScrollIndicator:true,
    showHorizontalScrollIndicator:true
});
var view = Ti.UI.createView({
    backgroundColor:'#336699',
    borderRadius:10,
    width:300,
    height:2000,
    top:10
});
scrollView.add(view);
Titanium.UI.currentWindow.add(scrollView);
```

[tableviews](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.UI.TableView-object) are also a common way to implement a scrollable view.

> What other options can I use while making the App for an android
>   device.

have a look at the [titanium api](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/). it displays which methods and views are available on android. you should also be aware of the multi density for android devices. so you need to provide youre images in multiple resolutions. have a look at the [titanium guidelines](http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Using+density-specific+resources+on+Android).

hope it helps