# Where to get sample Code for titanium code?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile

I am just a beginner in Titanium and searching for few sample source code to learn from and run. Downloading and working with kitchen sink or with the API is a big pain, to understand as well as to work with.

Although everything is there in both and they have given sample but that seems like not an implementation. I just want to have some source code to learn how, when and where to use the elements? How things work, how are they integrated etc.

Comment: Hello Sahil, You may argue that help and guide provided on appcelerator site is not sufficient but that is the best thing available on NET for Titanium Help. There is no other blog or web site which will provide better help than this.

Comment: @TheZero is there nothing available over the whole internet where someone has really started from a basic level and taking to a normal level. Because if you check I am not facing issue in understanding what element is what, my problem is in integrating them.[Check here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8485770/how-to-get-a-transition-for-windows-element-like-in-scroll-views) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this [Forging Titanium](http://vimeo.com/28122504) series on Vimeo.com to be one of the best. Just watch out this complete series. Beside  providing you with basics and advanced limelight on elements and functionality, also provide link to many github public repository we can follow and get numerous sample codes.

Answer (score 2):

Usually at the Q&A section there are samples of code. Just search what you are looking for: http://developer.appcelerator.com/questions/newest

The Wiki provides examples: http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Home

Even this website provides code samples, check out the Titanium Tag: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/titanium

And last, but not least, there seem to be more and more code samples in the API Docs: http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest

Good luck!

Comment: here was my main [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8485770/how-to-get-a-transition-for-windows-element-like-in-scroll-views). Then I asked about sample code for Android in titanium so that beside views I can know all other things as well.

Answer (score 1):

As an option, you can find good application samples on CodeCanyon. They're not free but you can learn a lot by examining how to start from scratch to build an application like;

- Simple Foursquare like apps
- Photo gallery apps
- TODO apps etc.

http://codecanyon.net/category/mobile/titanium

Comment: thanks for this link but I am looking for some real code because I am facing problem using Views and Windows.Check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8485770/how-to-get-a-transition-for-windows-element-like-in-scroll-views).